# WPF Maskable Texbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set mask for TextBox in Wpf Mvvm.

I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34228/WPF-Maskable-TextBox-for-Numeric-Values) article . and set `stringformat` for this in xaml.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding MaxValue,StringFormat=n0}"
             commonWPF:TextBoxMaskBehavior.Mask="Integer" />
```

When i use this without `StringFormat` it is ok, but when i use it, when formated value move `CaretIndex` .

for example:`123,4` is ok but when i press `5` result is `123,54` but 
The result should be `123,45`

Comment: The result should be 123,45... after 123,4 move caretindex befor of 4

Comment: If you move the caret to before the 4 the answer **will** be "123,54".

Comment: No, i don't change the caretindex. when i use stringformat 
The problem arises.

Comment: There is a cavet in article that you are using, '•Rejects symbols other than digits, negative signs, and the decimal separator.` ..... it seems non exhaustive  and N0 means no decimal places so what is this comma treated as ? dodgy!

Comment: Are you using a culture that has a decimal comma?

Comment: I want to format my view that the money be split 3 to 3 to number. for example show 125,458,142,000